# Thermodynamics Problems!

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

> A cylinder, 0.5 m long and of cross section $S$, closed at each end is fitted with a smooth thermally insulating piston, so as to contain gas in each end A and B. Initially, the piston is in equilibrium at a distance of 0.2 m from one end of the cylinder, and the gas in each compartment is at temperature 27 °C. The temperature of the smaller volume of gas A is now increased to 177 °C, while that of gas in the larger volume B is maintained at 27 °C. The piston moves through a distance of $X$ until a position is obtained.
>
> 1) Write an equation relating the initial and final pressure, volume and temperature of the gas in A.
>
> 2) Write an equation relating the initial and final pressure, volume and temperature of the gas in B.
>
> 3) Hence find the new position of equilibrium.

P.S. This is not my assignment or homework so you could feel free to explain.

Comment: This question reads like a homework or textbook problem, even if it was not assigned. Our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) extends to self-study problems that you have found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The volume $V$ of a cylinder is given as $V=\pi r^2 h$ where $h$ is the height and $r$ the radius. Since the cross-section of the cylinder is $S$, the radius is given as $r=S/2$.

Now, we know that the piston is at equilibrium in the initial position, and the equilibrium in this case is $p_\text{A} = p_\text{B}$ for the pressures of the corresponding gases.

We also know the ideal gas law, which, when adding the information above (and assuming the gases A and B behave ideally) is: $$pV = nRT \Longleftrightarrow p = \frac{nRT}{V} = \frac{nRT}{\pi (S/2)^2 x} = \frac{4nRT}{\pi S^2 x}$$
For the distance $x$ of the piston to one wall.

For gas A we have the initial and final conditions:
$$ p_\text{i}^{(\text{A})} = \frac{4n^{(\text{A})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 x_\text{i}} \; \text{and} \;\; p_\text{f}^{(\text{A})} = \frac{4n^{(\text{A})} RT_\text{f}}{\pi S^2 x_\text{f}} $$

And for B (with a total height of the cylinder of $h$):
$$ p_\text{i}^{(\text{B})} = \frac{4n^{(\text{B})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 (h-x_\text{i})} \; \text{and} \;\; p_\text{f}^{(\text{B})} = \frac{4n^{(\text{B})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 (h-x_\text{f})} $$

We know that the initial and final pressures were the same (equilibrium condition):
$$ \frac{4n^{(\text{A})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 x_\text{i}} = \frac{4n^{(\text{B})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 (h-x_\text{i})} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{n^{\text{(A)}}}{x_\text{i}} = \frac{n^{\text{(B)}}}{h - x_\text{i}}$$
$$ \frac{4n^{(\text{A})} RT_\text{f}}{\pi S^2 x_\text{f}} = \frac{4n^{(\text{B})} RT_\text{i}}{\pi S^2 (h-x_\text{f})} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{n^{\text{(A)}}T_\text{f}}{x_\text{f}} = \frac{n^{\text{(B)}}T_\text{i}}{h-x_\text{f}}$$

We can now solve both equations for $\frac{n^\text{(A)}}{n^\text{(B)}}$ and equate them:
$$ \frac{n^\text{(A)}}{n^\text{(B)}} = \frac{x_\text{i}}{h-x_\text{i}} \; \text{and} \;\; \frac{n^\text{(A)}}{n^\text{(B)}} = \frac{x_\text{f}T_\text{i}}{T_\text{f}(h-x_\text{f})} $$
$$ \frac{x_\text{i}}{h-x_\text{i}} = \frac{x_\text{f}T_\text{i}}{T_\text{f}(h-x_\text{f})}$$

Solving for $x_\text{f}$ gives us the final equation:
$$ x_\text{f} = \frac{\frac{hx_\text{i}T_\text{f}}{T_\text{i}(h-x_\text{i})}}{1 + \frac{x_\text{i}T_\text{f}}{T_\text{i}(h-x_\text{i})}}$$

For the values provided by you I get $x_\text{f} = 0.25~\mathrm{m}$, which is exactly in the middle.